# Account Locked attribute not getting added in response for scim2 GET Users API in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying retrieve the user list which have locked accounts in WSO2 IS 5.9 version.
I tried after adding account lock attribute to below claims:

- http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity
- urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0
- urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User
- urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User

I have followed below URL as well to add the custom claim:
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/extending-scim2-user-schemas/

```
{ "attributeURI":"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:accountLock",
 "attributeName":"accountLock",
 "dataType":"boolean",
 "multiValued":"false",
 "description":"Account lock",
 "required":"false",
 "caseExact":"false",
 "mutability":"readwrite",
 "returned":"default",
 "uniqueness":"none",
 "subAttributes":"null",
 "multiValuedAttributeChildName":"null",
 "canonicalValues":[],
"referenceTypes":[]
}
```

But still i am not able to get the accountLock attribute in response to GET Users API of scim2.

Response

````
   "totalResults": 10,
   "startIndex": 1,
   "itemsPerPage": 10,
   "schemas": [
       "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse"
   ],
   "Resources": [
       
       {
           "emails": [
               "divya@abc.com"
           ],
           "meta": {
               "created": "2020-06-25T07:49:35.465Z",
               "lastModified": "2020-06-25T11:20:13.482Z",
               "resourceType": "User"
           },
           "name": {
               "givenName": "guest",
               "familyName": "guest"
           },
           "groups": [
               {
                   "display": "Application/sp1"
               },
               {
                   "display": "Application/sp2"
               },
               {
                   "display": "Application/Read"
               }
           ],
           "id": "9ffbed2e-3703-470c-a2c8-e738f4c09709",
           "userName": "guest12"
       }
   ]}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following reasons may cause to accoutLock attribute does not appear in SCIM2 GET user response.

1. You might missed to add the new attribute ( "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:accountLock") **as a sub attribute** of urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User object. (Point 3 in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/extending-scim2-user-schemas/#extending-the-scim-20-api.
   "subAttributes":"**accoutLock** verifyEmail askPassword employeeNumber costCenter organization division department manager")

   ````
     "attributeURI":"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User",
     "attributeName":"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User",
     "dataType":"complex",
     "multiValued":"false",
     "description":"Enterprise User",
     "required":"false",
     "caseExact":"false",
     "mutability":"readWrite",
     "returned":"default",
     "uniqueness":"none",
     "subAttributes":"accoutLock verifyEmail askPassword employeeNumber costCenter organization division department manager",
     "canonicalValues":[],
     "referenceTypes":["external"]
     }```
   ````
2. The mapped attribute of the added custom claim (https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/extending-scim2-user-schemas/#add-the-custom-claim) should be an existing attribute in LDAP schema if you are using the default LDAP userstore. (However, if you have done this mistake you won't be able to update/add claim value. It gives `One or more attributes you are trying to add/update are not supported by underlying LDAP for user:` error)
3. The response of SCIM2 GET users doesn't contain the attributes which don't have a value. Thus, set true/false to the claim value.

Moreover, it is enough to add the new attribute to urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User claim dialect. Follow steps in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/extending-scim2-user-schemas/

Comment: We had already added sub-attribute as accountLock so we have covered point 1. Regarding point 2, we are using JDBC as primary store so is there any additional setting that we need to do since account locked claim is already added in http://wso2.org/claims. Lastly, on point 3, account locked attribute has true for "Supported by default" . in which table we can find the values for this attribute in wso2 database?

Comment: If there is no value associated with the accoutLock attribute for that user then the accoutLock attribute will not be shown in the scim response. Since you have ticked "Supported by default" you can set a value to the claim through the user profile from the management console. Ticking "Supported by default" doesn't add any default value to the attribute. scim will only return attributes containing values.

Comment: @Janak I have created a new guest user and ticked/selected the Account Locked attribute, locking this user account,then this value should get set. After this also, i am unable to get this attribute in response of https://<ip_address>/scim2/Users

Comment: @DivyaJain  for the External claim URI: urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:accountLock did you map http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountLocked local claim? or a custom claim which has 'accountLock' as mapped attribute ?

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna I have mapped urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:accountLock to wso2.org/claims/identity/accountLocked local claim.

Comment: If that mapping is there and you have ticketed on a particular user's  Account Locked attribute. That should be returned in the response as     `"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User": {
        "accountLock": true
    }`.  If you want to verify, "idn_identity_user_data" is the database table which stores http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountLocked value.

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna I could see the values in the mentioned table but still not able to get the attribute in the response.

Comment: @DivyaJain I could reproduce this issue in IS 5.9 GA released pack. If you check on `https://<ip_address>/scim2/Users/<user_id>` request you can see that account lock attribute. There is a reported issue regarding "Identity claims are not returning When a GET request is sent to SCIM2 Users resource without specifying an ID" (https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/6741). It is fixed in 5.10 as well as IS-5.9 latest WUM updated pack.

Comment: Thanks @AnuradhaKarunarathna for the clarification. However, when I am trying to update the wso2is-5.9 product via WUM, its asking me to add the product whereas i have already installed it on my local machine and contain changes as well. Is there any other way to update the GA released pack?